# C# Return an object from a list based on index

Tags: c#, list

I need to make some changes so that I only retrieve one object at a time from my list instead of the entire list as I do now.

Right now ive got a private list in class B with a property returning the entire list basically making it public anyway and I want to change this.

The way class a looks(the ui class operating with the list) is, I enter some data validate it and send it to class B which in turn packages it into a list of objects based on the input.

Then class A needs to loop this list and add it to a listview for displaying it which looks like this at the moment:

```
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        foreach ([Object] o in CLassB.getList())
        {
            lvi = new ListViewItem(o.property0);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(o.property1);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(o.property2);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(o.property3);
        }
    }
```

Object is my abstract class which controls how the different types of items are added and getList() is my method in class B returning the entire list.

The thing is these propertys are the common ones all classes share the there are some that arent, like a textbox that you enter specific text about the object and so on which is displayed like this:

```
    private void lvRegistered_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Listview.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach ([Object] ob in ClassB.getList())
            {
                if (Listview.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text == ob.id.ToString())
                {
                    TextBox.Clear();
                    TextBox.Text = ob.property4;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now this all works great at the moment but now I have a returned list to operate on but I dont want to return the list making it public I want to return one object of the list based on an index number (yes the functionality will be exactly the same, I made a method returning the count of the private list so I can loop over it and return all). This is for practicing OOP for when I dont want to return everything.

How would this be done? All I can think of is making a new list, take an int as input and search my private list and find the index then add that to the other list and return that list, but I dont know if this is good practice or the best way to do it? Well I havent looked into how to "copy" one element over to next list either but might aswell check and see if theres a better way to do things?

Just get the feeling im "taking the long way around" this way

Comment: So just expose `ClassB.GetItemByIndex(int index)` rather than `ClassB.getList()`, or what is your question?

Comment: You can use list.AsReadOnly() method (http://goo.gl/Ue1kA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure to understand, but how about a simple `GetById` method?

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    private List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();

    public void Add(Foo foo)
    {
        this.list.Add(foo);
    }

    public Foo GetById(int id)
    {
        return this.list.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == id);
    }
}

....

Test test = new Test();
test.Add(new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "1" });
test.Add(new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "2" });
test.Add(new Foo { Id = 3, Name = "3" });

Foo foo2 = test.GetById(2);
```

Comment: Yea this looks like it would work, already do have an id. Only prob I see is I serialize and deserialize my list so if I were to remove id 3 for example I could do a forloop starting at 1 and going the count of the list looking for id`s, gonna have to fix that somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand completely, but it sounds like you could resolve this be creating an indexer on class B to return the item you want:

```
public object this[int index] {
  get {
    return list[index];
  }
}
```

change 'object' to whatever your class type actually is.

You can then access the items as if class B was an array:

```
object item = classB[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use List.AsReadOnly() Method.

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<Double> MyList {
        get {
            return myList.AsReadOnly();
        }
}
private List<Double> myList;
```

2) Use index method in the class.

```
public Double this[int index] {
        get {
            return myList[index];
        }
        set {
            myList[index] = value;
        }
 }
private List<Double> myList;
```

Comment: Problem with asreadonly is that it still returns the entire list right? The point is to make (even though for this specifik task I want to return everyhting) the list retrive what I allow it to, say that I store sensitive data or something, then every person cant access everything from the list just the data specified by the search.

Answer (score 0):

Did about the same as suggested by Ken2k but instead I went with this:

```
    public [Class] getListItem(int index)
    {
        return myList.ElementAt(id);
    }
```

which in turn is used in my other class that displays the info like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < am.getCount(); i++)
            {
                ListViewItem = new ListViewItem([class reference].getList(i).[property].ToString());
                ListViewItems.SubItems.Add([class reference].getList(i).[property]);
            }
```

Thanks everyone for all your help on this.